# Advanced multiple join for mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

So I have a query that gives me three numbers, I then want to look up these numbers from another table and get the name and url associated with them.

So I have a products table that i query, and that provides me these three numbers, but as there are 3 numbers, an inner join wouldnt work.

So I am essentially just trying to look up the name and url, of 3 numbers from the same table, and wondering how the most efficient way to achieve this would be.

```
$qry = mysqli_query($this->con,"SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_id=$this->id");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qry);
$main = $row['main_id'];
$cat = $row['categories_id'];
$sub = $row['sub_cat_id'];
```

So I can do a query for each number individually, but then that is a total of 4 queries. I was wondering if this could be done in just one, or possibly even 2.

Comment: can you share some sample data and expected result?

Comment: Look up the `IN` sql syntax like `WHERE column IN (1,2,3)` although if you described the table(s) structure I would bet we could work out a `JOIN` syntax that would work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to say for sure without seeing some table structure and sample data, but something like this may work (where `othertable` is the name of the other table you are pulling urls and names from):

```
select p.mail_id, 
p.categories_id, 
p.sub_cat_id,
o1.url mail_id_url,
o1.name mail_id_name,
o2.url categories_id_url,
o2.name categories_id_name,
o3.url sub_cat_id_url,
o3.name sub_cat_id_name
from products p
join othertable o1 on o1.mail_id = p.mail_id
join othertable o2 on o2.categories_id = p.categories_id
join othertable o3 on o3.sub_cat_id = p.sub_cat_id
where p.product_id = $this->id
```

This assumes that a record exits in othertable for every id that you are looking up.